# What should be tested in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, testing, unit-testing

At work, we've just started on a heavily Javascript based application (actually using Coffeescript, but still), of which I've been implementing an automated test system using JsTestDriver and fabric.

We've never written something with this much Javascript, so up until now we've never done any Javascript testing. I'm unsure what exactly we should be testing in our unit tests. We've written JQuery plugins for various things, so it's quite obvious that they should be verified for correctness as much as possible with JsTestDriver, but everyone else in my team seems to think that we should be testing the page level Javascript as well.

I don't think we should be testing page level Javascript as unit tests, but instead using a system like Selenium to verify everything works as expected. My main reasoning for this is that at the moment, page level Javascript tests are guaranteed to fail through JsTestDriver, because they're trying to access elements on the DOM that can't possibly exist.

So, what should be unit tested in Javascript?

Comment: You isolate any javascript code you've written into modules. Then you simply test the inputs and outputs of those modules. Any modules that deal with the DOM means you have to test the DOM. Use a better tool then jsTestDriver.

Comment: You should be unit testing business logic.  If your business logic and elements on the DOM are intertwined then you have a design flaw.  Abstract out as much business logic from the page elements as possible so that it can be properly unit tested.  For DOM element interaction verification you should be using Selenium.

Comment: Well, in the spirit of the question, @Raynos, could you suggest a better tool?

Comment: @maple_shaft, that's essentially what the jQuery plugins we've written are; business logic. UI controls for things like user selection, modal dialogs and whatnot. The problem is, the controls use the DOM to store/represent results from ajax calls and user input, so there's no way to verify them without a DOM, that I know of.

Comment: @NathanHoad You write unit tests that get run in the browser itself, nodeunit, qunit and jasmine are sensible tools. When running in the browser you have the DOM. You could use a tool like testling to automate browser testing.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking toward jsTestDriver as it claimed be able to run in the browser, which, while technically true, I've discovered isn't the same as running with QUnit. I've been working on my own tool at the moment that uses QUnit, with a custom Django debug toolbar panel. Using Selenium I'll be able to detect failing tests. Also, I doubt my boss would pay for testling, although it does look pretty good!

Comment: @Raynos: jsTestDriver does run in the browser, but it runs in an (effectively) empty page. It's not that the DOM is missing, but that the elements are missing. (It also has adapters for qUint and Jasmine.)

Comment: @NathanHoad I personally just write a jasmine/nodeunit unit test suite and manually run it in all browsers. In theory you can write a little script to open all these browsers for you, that's about as automated as it gets. Anything more would just involve you rewriting a mediocre version of testling ;)

Comment: @Raynos, I agree, it will be a mediocre version of testling! However my boss is huge on large scale automated testing (our last product has a few hundred unit tests that run every day) so a Selenium script that runs through each page and runs the tests is what I'll go with. It doesn't need to be particularly fancy, haha :P

Comment: @NathanHoad Why you no support OS and buy testling :(. Buying software is always cheaper then writing it in house, especially if it does what you want.

Comment: Hmm we have some pretty unique needs here though, so writing software in house is pretty much what always happens. What usually happens is we find there's a limitation in the system we're using, and have to add or change something - SaaS like Testling doesn't seem to give us that option.

Comment: related: [How do you unit test your javascript](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/53963/how-do-you-unit-test-your-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test everything you can.

Pure logic can be tested easily.

If your code interacts with the DOM or the network, it's much harder.

If you can abstract out a piece of code to work on an arbitrary DOM element instead of a specific one, then you can test it more easily. (Make the element to work on a parameter).

Code that uses Ajax can be tested by simply calling the callback function with fixed data. I've had some tests where I overwrote `$.ajax` with my own function. Just make sure you put the real one back when you're done!

What you'll find is that "page level javascript" really means, "tightly coupled code," and if you decouple the parts of the code, you can test them independently.

(Selenium is not a unit testing tool. It's great for high-level scenarios, but you can't test-drive with it, and it doesn't work in an isolated environment.)

Comment: jasmine can mock function calls and response data, you might look into that instead of overriding functions.

Comment: I should clarify - we have functions and such on each page. I was talking more about testing the code that executes inside `$(document).ready(...)`.

Comment: It's all a matter of how big that `...` is. :-) I feel like you should be able to get that down to a single named function that is also tested. Then your untested code is a single line. (Now that's a goal, not a given. In practice I've always had more than one line of untested code.)

Comment: @SeanMcMillan - I find it very difficult to test parts of an application which only affects the DOM, for example, a function which only binds several events to some DOM elements. How would you check that those events were written properly? not something unit tests can do, but real browser clicking and checking (using selenium or whatever)

Comment: @vsync: You can test that, say, a click handler was attached to a given DOM element pretty easily. I don't think it's possible to test that 'click' is the right handler, and that you've attached it to the right element.

Comment: @SeanMcMillan - why should you even test something like that? events might change, the DOM elements might change..callback pointers might change..it's such a hassle keeping those tests in sync with every minor change wouldn't you say?

Comment: @vsync: You probably shouldn't, honestly. But if you do, I would break down the borders so that the tests don't have to be updated for minor changes.

Answer (score 5):

Test algorithms. GUI-closely related parts are more depended on specific browser so have to be tested using selenium-like utils.

Your code, of course, must contain algorithms as an isolated pieces of code, if it doesn't then unit testing is almost impossible.

jquery plugins, btw, are not easy unit-testable.

Comment: All good points! I agree that they're not easily unit testable as well, depending on how they're written.

Answer (score -1):

I used to work with Java and from what I see unit testing Java is easier than unit testing JavaScript because Java is more rigid.

I'm sold on that test-driven development is the best thing so I'm also exploring how to unit test JavaScript. In Java I've mocked out the code that made connection to the database, the Data Access Objects, and I compare that to the code in JavaScript that changes the DOM and the code that makes AJAX calls to the server.

What I'm getting at is that it seems to me that what should be tested is the logic explicitly. For example, you don't want to make an AJAX call when you run unit tests because (a) you need the server to be running and (b) it is slow and one of the guidelines of unit testing is that it needs to be super fast so that the developers don't avoid running them like every minute.

Another guideline is for the continuous integration process to send an e-mail saying that it found a unit test that failed.